# How to delete cookie when silverlight application is closed?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I am creating an application with silverlight 3.0 .
In This application I had create one cookie 
Now if any end user will close browser then i want to delete data from that cookie.
How can i delete that data from silverlight application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The non persistent cookie will automatically delete when the browser will be closed...

> If you are using ASP; the session cookie is non persistent cookie and you can store things in ASP' session.